# Pipelined function gives "PLS-00630" error upon compilation

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm new to table functions. I'm receiving a "PLS-00630 pipelined functions must have a supported collection return type" when trying to compile a package with the function.

The intent of the function is return a list of records from a RUN_LOG audit table. It takes an input date which would return records for that date.

The data types of the PROCS_COMPLETED object matches the RUN_LOG table.

Created these objects:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE PROCS_COMPLETED IS OBJECT (
    RECORD_ID      NUMBER
  , RUN_START_DATE DATE
  , RUN_END_DATE   DATE
  , OWNER          VARCHAR2(50)
  , PROC_NAME      VARCHAR2(162)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE PROCS_COMPLETED_INFO IS TABLE OF PROCS_COMPLETED;
```

Function declaration in package spec:

```
FUNCTION GET_PROCS_COMPLETED(ID_DATE IN DATE) RETURN PROCS_COMPLETED PIPELINED;
```

Function in package body:

```
FUNCTION GET_PROCS_COMPLETED(ID_DATE IN DATE) RETURN PROCS_COMPLETED PIPELINED AS
BEGIN
  FOR C_PROCS_COMPLETED IN (
                            SELECT r.RECORD_ID
                                 , r.RUN_START_DATE
                                 , r.RUN_END_DATE
                                 , r.OWNER
                                 , r.PROC_NAME
                              FROM RUN_LOG r
                             WHERE TRUNC(r.RUN_START_DATE) = TRUNC(ID_DATE)
                           )
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW (PROCS_COMPLETED_INFO
               (  C_PROCS_COMPLETED.RECORD_ID
                , C_PROCS_COMPLETED.RUN_START_DATE
                , C_PROCS_COMPLETED.RUN_END_DATE
                , C_PROCS_COMPLETED.OWNER
                , C_PROCS_COMPLETED.PROC_NAME
               )
             );
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: In the function declaration, the return type should be collection variable.. ie PROCS_COMPLETED_INFO..

Comment: By the way, your caps lock is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the error message carefully, it actually tells you what's wrong:

> pipelined functions must have a supported **collection** return type

(emphasis mine).

So, `RETURN PROCS_COMPLETED_INFO`.

Another mistake is to attempt to pipe the collection type -- `PIPE ROW (PROCS_COMPLETED_INFO(...))` -- while you want to pipe a `ROW`: `PIPE ROW (PROCS_COMPLETED(...))`

Comment: thank you. Yes, that makes sense and is now working.